# How to use Identity Server 3 for Servicestack service Authentication?

Tags: authentication, service, servicestack, identityserver3

I am using Service stack version `3.9.71` for service creation.

Now we have requirement to authentication this service. how we can authenticate servicestack service using Identity Server 3? I have read [service stack document page.](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) But I am not find any solution for Identity Server 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://estynedwards.com/blog/2016/01/30/ServiceStack-IdentityServer-Angular/

The section relevant to you is the process of creating a custom authprovider for ServiceStack, so that you can integrate with an OpenID Connect authentication provider (in your case Identity Server 3).

There does not seem to be an [official authprovider for OpenID Connect](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/integration-with-custom-identity-provider/856) yet

Comment: I have tried solution provided in first link. But I thinks this solution is for V 4.0 not V3.9.

Comment: Okay, the answer still stands though. You're going to need to create yourself an OpenID Connect authprovider for ServiceStack, as there's no out of the box support for it yet. Might be a worthwhile OSS/contribution project.